Spray or solution to keep pests out of sink cabinet
We have a new kitchen sink and mice are coming up from the basement through these water supply port holes and making a mess underneath the sink:

I'm looking to spray/apply some type of foam or other material that will be easy to install and that will prevent the mice from getting in here. I realize mice can chew through just about anything but I have to imagine there is some solution to make it really, really difficult for them. Any takers?

You may have asked an XY question (about your proposed solution instead of your actual problem). Please revise to ask about what you're trying to accomplish instead.

@JimmyJames, any trap is a temporary solution unless all exterior access points have been dealt with. That's not the scope of this question.

@isherwood Which is why I didn't add it as answer. It was a frame-challenge. If you have a location where mice are known to visit and easy for the homeowner to access, that's an opportunity. Blocking the access is just out-of-sight, out-of-mind.

I would use a split pipe flange:

Should be available from most hardware stores. Look for one that is made of metal and not plastic and screw it down. Then, I would look into dealing with the mice in the basement issue.
Image source: Homedepot

Good idea, I had the same concept. One thought, though: SE wants folks to put attribution for pictures that are posted, if the poster didn't take the picture themselves. A link to the source of the picture usually suffices.

The solution I've read of regarding mice and foam is to fill a mouse access area with steel wool, then fill the steel wool with foam by jamming the foam nozzle into the wool and dispensing the foam. Mice don't like to chew through steel wool.
One consideration in doing this is that the area the pipes come through seems to be large and hollow, so the foam may push the steel wool around and not keep the wool up against the opening where the pipes come through.
Another idea is to cover the openings with split flange escutcheon plates, like these:


source
They clamp around the pipe, then you could silicone or caulk them down, so you could remove them in the future if needed by cutting the silicone or caulk. The metal may block the mice behind the cover.

You can also purchase copper wire mesh as an alternative to steel wool.
